# Will the Vulkan api be released for the Mac OS platform?

Tags: vulkan

Khronos group has released [Vulkan API](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/). Will implementations of the Vulkan API be released for the Mac OS platform?

Comment: According to [this overview](https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/library/overview/Vk_201602_Overview_Feb16.pdf) (Page 10) there will be an "Vulkan and OpenGL ES over Metal" (in development). Molten/MetalVK/MetalGL

Comment: @Constantin: Good luck with implementing Vulkan's memory model on top of Metal's...

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. Apple is moving forward with their Metal API which is similar but not directly compatible. There are some projects in the works to translate between Vulkan and Metal like Wine/Cider do for DirectX and OpenGL but only time will tell if performance is sufficient for real use.